# should I change the tyres soon?

Tags: tires, car

My car's tires are 3+ years old and the front is like in image.
There are some cracks between the treads on the front tires.

[image: front tire 1]
[image: front tire 2]
[image: front tire 3]

It is quite similar to what's been posted here:
[Do these tyre cracks necessitate replacement?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/43433/do-these-tyre-cracks-necessitate-replacement)

Anyway, please let me have your opinion.

Should I replace the tires soon?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the tires rub the curbs often, the side walls will look better if that stops . The tread looks  like it has some miles remaining but start planning for replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, please get new ones.

1. Especially the sidewalls are rather thin. So those deeper scratches on the sides are a little bit worrying.
2. Overall, those cracks on the surface show that **the rubber has hardened**. You will not have the best grip, which affects not only turning ability but more importantly **brake distance** and can also cause you to spin off course far more easily.

Comment: +1 for the **hardened**. Looks like the tread depth (the common measure for tire life) _may_ pass muster (barely so), the tire looks old and the rubber no longer pliable so its grip could be catastrophically poor.